# vk openapi likes.add

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Использую библиотеку вк openapi.js. Все методы которые вызывал работали. Сейчас столкнулся с методами [likes.add](https://vk.com/dev/likes.add) и [likes.delete](https://vk.com/dev/likes.delete) а они отвечают отказом доступа. Подскажите в что я делаю не так.

```
VK.Api.call('likes.add', {
    type: 'post',
    owner_id: -2158488,
    item_id: 651604,
    v:'5.60'
  }, function (r){
    console.log('r', r);
  });
```

В console

`Object 
  error: Object
    error_code: 15
    error_msg: "Access denied: no access to call this method"`

Битовая маска при авторизации `73758`

Comment: Похоже это только для Standalone

Comment: openapi  авторизацию проводит через VK.Init({ apiId: номер приложения})

Comment: И? это не standalone

Comment: Простите, а что такое standalone ?

Comment: ну это, грубо говоря, то, что будет у каждого пользователя в единственном экземпляре. Например на компе, на телефоне. как программа. То есть это может быть мобильное приложение на андройд/айфон/виндофон, ПК программа, а не сайт с общим доступом

Comment: Мне казалось имеется ввиду вк standalone приложение. Интересное мнение, посмотрим что другие скажут, возможно вы правы.

Comment: `Мне казалось имеется ввиду вк standalone приложение.` - а чем они отличаются? standalone он и в Африке standalone. Это общепринятое понятие. если нужно подтверждение... ну вот https://vk.com/dev/access_token ....цитата: `Получить ключ доступа пользователя можно одним из этих способов:
Implicit flow. Для работы с API от имени пользователя в Javascript-приложениях и Standalone-клиентах (десктопных или мобильных).` ............. **Standalone-клиентах (десктопных или мобильных).**

Comment: авторизация проходит от юзера через standalone приложение вк. юзер подтверждает права доступа, получает токен и с этим токеном идет обращение к вк, от юзера. это разве не относится к одному из методов , точнее к этому `от  имени пользователя в Javascript-приложениях `

Answer (score 3):

Метод [`likes.add`](https://vk.com/dev/likes.add) можно использовать только в standalone-приложениях. Это такие приложения, которые, простыми словами, имеют более расширенный доступ к системе пользователя, чем обычный веб-сайт. Например, мобильные клиенты, десктопные программы и даже расширения для браузеров (некоторых ограничений, например CORS, у них нет, а также они могут читать содержимое любой вкладки). Получить токен standalone-приложения, у которого не было бы ограничений на вызовы методов API, через веб-сайт нельзя. Вообще. Никак.

Дело в том, что получить токен без ограничений можно только в том случае, если в качестве параметра `redirect_uri` указан адрес `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`. Этот параметр отвечает за то, куда будет перенаправлен пользователь после авторизации в приложении. И после авторизации пользователя токен отобразится в адресной строке браузера примерно вот так:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492&state=123456
```

К сожалению, не существует такой магии, которая бы позволила получить содержимое hash-строки другой вкладки. А потенциальные лазейки (например, iFrame) ВКонтакте закрыли. Именно поэтому самостоятельно дёрнуть этот токен вы и не сможете, даже если пользователь успешно авторизуется в приложении. Тем не менее, мобильные и десктопные приложения, а также браузерные расширения обладают достаточным функционалом, чтобы сделать это.

Сделано это, очевидно, для того, чтобы пользователи не рисковали, авторизовываясь на недобросовестных сайтах. Никому ведь не хочется увидеть свой лайк под записью о какой-нибудь гадости, или, скажем, внезапно обнаружить в своих подписках какое-нибудь сообщество с контентом для взрослых.

Но вы можете авторизовать пользователя и попросить его скопировать токен в форму на вашем сайте. А дальше уже вызывать необходимые вам методы через JSONP или с бэкэнда. Open API в таком случае не подойдет, т.к. он не умеет принимать кастомные токены. Только учтите, что после авторизации у пользователя черным по белому будет написано, чтобы он никуда не копировал токен. Но так лучше не делать. Не исключено, что это нарушает какие-нибудь правила ВКонтакте, за что они могут просто отключить ваше приложение, а также это как-никак плохо влияет на UX.