# Нет прав доступа к группе

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Хочу получить забаненных пользователей группы. 
Но выдает ошибку

```
{"error":{"error_code":15,"error_msg":"Access denied: no access to call this method","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"groups.getBanned"},{"key":"group_id","value":"ХХХХХХХ"},{"key":"v","value":"5.62"}]}}
```

Права админа группы у меня есть, при установке спрашиваю доступ к группам:

```
"https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=".APP_ID."&display=page&redirect_uri=".REDIRECT_URI."&scope=groups&revoke=1&response_type=code&v=".V
```

В приложении также указано спрашивать доступ к группам.

Токен валидный.
Сайт на локалхлосте.

`account.getAppPermissions` возвращает битовую маску 262144  - Доступ к группам пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`groups.getBanned`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getBanned) можно вызывать только с указанием токена, полученным при авторизации в standalone-приложении по схеме [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user). При этом при авторизации параметр `redirect_uri` должен быть обязательно равен значению `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`.

Подробно про авторизацию я объяснял в ответе на этот вопрос: [vk openapi likes.add](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612693/212210). Там у автора точно такая же проблема, как у вас, только с другим методом.

Comment: возможно вы подкажете как можно использовать этот токен из php ?
Client API ?

Comment: @Hardc0re, я все подробно объяснил в вопросе по приведенной ссылке.