# Почему не репостится?Предварительно все подключил, авторизовался и дал такие права: group wall

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

```
test.onclick = function(){ 
VK.api("wall.repost", {"object": "wall-84392011_165517"}, function (r) { 
if (r.response) 
alert(r.response); 
}); 
}
```

Comment: ну так что прилетает в `r`? выведи в консоль - посмотри... может ошибки сыпятся? так загляни в консоль - посмотри. А может у тебя даже клик не работает.

Comment: Как вывести в консоль?

Comment: жесть.....`console.log`...... ты не умеешь в консоль, а уже пытаешься в апи? серьезно?

Comment: а что туда нужно вывести?

Answer (score 0):

Метод [`wall.repost`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.repost) доступен только [standalone-приложениям](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user), о чем написано в описании метода. Вы пытаетесь обратиться к нему с помощью JavaScript, а значит у вас приложение либо типа «вебсайт», либо iFrame. У приложений этих типов набор возможностей ограничен в целях безопасности. Подробнее на тему типов приложений я писал в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612693/212210).